# Selecting data from a listbx that came from an array

Tags: c#

I was wondering - how would I go about doing something when an item in a list box is selected when the data comes from an array.

I have the following in a class called "global"

```
public static string[] globalPizzaSizeMENU = new string[4] { "8 Inch", "10 Inch", "12 Inch", "14 Inch" };
```

And I have this to grab the data

```
size.Items.AddRange(global.globalPizzaSizeMENU);
```

When the user presses a button I want whatever is selected to be stored and it needs to work with more than one selection. For example - the user could have 2 8 Inch and 1 10 Inch.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I get it but I will do my best to help.
First off you are not putting anything into the size array. You are just incrementing its range. This is very rudimentary but it should work.
 This would get when the users mouse is down.

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Then in your class called global you could write

```
public static int[] numberofeachsize = new int[4] { "0", "0", "0", "0" };
```

and in the normal area

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
     string size_selected = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
     size.Add(size_selected);
     if(size_selected.ToUpper() == ("8 Inch").ToUpper()){
          global.numberofeachsize[0] +=1;
     }
     if(size_selected.ToUpper() == ("10 Inch").ToUpper()){
          global.numberofeachsize[1] +=1;
     }
     if(size_selected.ToUpper() == ("12 Inch").ToUpper()){
          global.numberofeachsize[2] +=1;
     }
     if(size_selected.ToUpper() == ("14 Inch").ToUpper()){
          global.numberofeachsize[3] +=1;
     }
}
```

That should be basic but should work for when the person clicks.